# How to search an array of objects and create a new array of objects matching a certain criteria

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to search an array of objects and create a new array of objects matching a certain criteria.

For example:

```
const locations = [
    {
      id: 1,
      location: "Sydeny",
      state: "nsw",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      location: "Melbourne",
      state: "victoria",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      location: "Newcastle",
      state: "nsw",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      location: "Perth",
      state: "wa",
    },
];
```

I would like to create a new array of all the objects that match the state of nsw.

I have tried the .filter array method, but it only returns the first object.

```
  const result = locations?.find(
      ({ state }) => state === 'nsw'
    );
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @CBroe I've tried the .filter method and its only returning the first result that matches.

Comment: Then _show us_ what you tried, how else are we supposed to figure out how you managed to get it wrong. _"and its only returning the first result that matches"_ - no, that is definitively not what `.filter()` does. If you use it correctly ...

Comment: what is search criteria.. ?

Comment: state is the search criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `filter()` method like comments suggest

```js
const locations = [
    {
      id: 1,
      location: "Sydeny",
      state: "nsw",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      location: "Melbourne",
      state: "victoria",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      location: "Newcastle",
      state: "nsw",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      location: "Perth",
      state: "wa",
    },
];

const result = locations.filter(ele => ele.state=='nsw');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, can you tell me why what I tried above only returned the first result?

Comment: @herbie Thats because you used `find()`. That method returns the first element that matches your criteria, not all of them

Comment: Thanks Chris, my bad I accidentally used .find, I thought I was using .filter. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Array.find() method, and it only returns the first occurrence. You must change it by Array.filter():

```
  const result = locations?.filter(
      ({ state }) => state === 'nsw'
    );
```

Comment: Thank you, good spot. It was an accidental mistake by me.